# issue in post in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a short example of `POST`

```
var p = {Name: obj.Name,  Age: obj.Age},
    str = JSON.stringify(p);

$.post("test.php", str, function (data) {
    alert("Post finished");
}).success(function () {
    alert("second success");
}).error(function() { 
    alert("error");
});
```

When I run above code, It throws an error message of `404 not found` from `test.php`.

I created this file `test.php` in my project.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you try opening test.php directly in the browser before posting this question?

Comment: This seems `PHP` problem rather than `jQuery` problem, because you should know how to set `root directory` of PHP pages and then use those `URI` with `$.post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in  `post` method is the `url` that you would want to send the `post data`.

`HTTP 404` means that url given is not found in the server.

Since there is no `test.php` that would receive your data, you will get this error.

You should create a `test.php` file that you accept your request.

Another thing is, you don't need to `stringify` JSON object while sending it to the server, `jquery` handles this automatically. Just send the `obj` as `post data`.

```
var p = { Name : "John",  Age : 23};
$.post("test.php", p).done(function(data){   
     alert("Post finished");    
}).success(function() {
    alert("second success");
}).error(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means the page couldn't be found. Are you sure it exists? Does it exist in the document root or did you mean the current folder:

```
$.post("/test.php", str , function(data){ 
        ^
```

Have you checked the request using FireBug for Firefox or Chrome's developer tools? What happens if you try to access that URL directly using your user-agent?

Comment: I created it under my project with empty file

Comment: I tried to look on the network tab in Chrome but I can see only the error

Comment: is it ok that the file is in my project ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "my project".

Comment: when I ran it from the user-agent I don't get any error

Comment: @user1365697 is the file in a subfolder? E.g. `http://example.com/subfolder/test.php`?

Comment: no it is under TEST and all the files is in WebContent

Comment: What is "TEST"??? A directory? A domain? Adn what is "WebContent"?

Comment: It is in the same folder as the page that contains the above jQuery?